# Präpositionen für Zahlung

Tags: preposition

Kann jemand bestätigen, dass ich in diesen Beispielen die korrekten Präpositionen benutzt habe?

- Eine Zahlung **auf** ein Konto machen.
- Eine Zahlung **ins** Ausland machen.
- Eine Zahlung **nach** Österreich machen.

Für mich die Hauptfrage ist der letzte Satz.

Comment: Ich würde keine „Zahlung machen“, aber das ist ja nicht gefragt. Die Präpositionen scheinen mir OK.

Comment: @chirlu: Kaum jemand will das, aber meist bleibt einem nichts anderes übrig. Aber ich vermute, deine Kritik ist sprachlicher Natur, nur kann ich sie nicht nachvollziehen. Man *macht* Zahlungen oder man *tätigt* Zahlungen. Mir fällt kein anderes Verb ein, dass man stattdessen verwenden könnte. Wie würdest du diese Sätze formulieren?

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Vermutlich würde ich _überweisen_, _einzahlen_ o.ä. Wenn es aber unbedingt eine _Zahlung_ sein muß, dann würde ich die wohl _vornehmen_ (eventuell auch _tätigen_, wie du schreibst) oder _veranlassen_, aber nicht _machen_.

Comment: @chirlu:@Hubert Schölnast: Danke euch beiden, ich habe aus euer Kommentaren mehr gelernt, als ich erwartet habe. Ich denke meine Frage ist so formuliert, dass keine vollständige Antwort gebraucht ist. Könnt ihr doch eine Antwort schreiben und z.B. die übrigen möglichen Präpositionen für Zahlung nennen?

Comment: Worum genau geht es dir eigentlich? Sind es Möglichkeiten über einen Geldfluss zu sprechen, oder geht es um die Präpositionen für Bewegungen auf ein Ziel zu?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: über einen Geldfluss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prepositions are correct.

There is this really cool website, which tells you how to handle german words: http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Zahlung

When you have a look at the fourth box (DWDS-Wortprofil 3.0) you'll find a tab which says "Zahlung hat Präpositionalgruppe". In this tab you'll find the most common examples coordinating with "Zahlung" and these can be really helpful.

Answer (score -3):

Eine Zahlung auf ein Konto machen.
Eine Zahlung ins Ausland machen.
Eine Zahlung nach Österreich machen.

They are correct.

How do you know they are?

You don't.

You could say.
Ich habe Geld in das Konto überwiesen.
Ich habe Geld in das Ausland überwiesen.
Ich habe Geld in das Österreich überwiesen.

Zahlung "aufs Ausland" und "aufs Österreich" however don't really work. Because they are bigger than you. So you can put stuff inside them but not on top of them. Unless in the future we invent hugely big paper notes.

Comment: “You could say _Ich habe Geld in das Konto überwiesen._ … _Ich habe Geld in das Österreich überwiesen._” Well, you certainly _could_ say so, but everyone listening would be shaking their heads.